# Getting BC30519 from an expression for an axis label that uses DatePart

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a category group with the following expression for the axis label:

```
=DatePart("yyyy",Fields!CreateDate.Value, "Orders")
```

I receive the following error:

```
The Label expression for the chart contains an error: 
[BC30519] Overload resolution failed because no acessible 
'DatePart' can be called without a narrowing conversion.
```

This doesn't look complicated or unusual, but it does not work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd parameter in DatePart function cannot be string. Try

```
=DatePart("yyyy",Fields!CreateDate.Value)
```

Comment: And please revisit other answers to your older questions. If you won't be accepting answers you won't get any new ones.